# Hashing in Java

Tags: java, hash

I have a `Long` and a `String`. I want to create a hash of both of those object. Meaning, I want some function that will take arbitrary number of objects and return me one hash value. Does such a function exits?

Something like this:

```
public int getHash(Object... objects)
{
     //somehow returns a hash of all these objects
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at `Arrays.hashCode(Object[])`.

It doesn't accept varargs, but you can wrap it with your own varargs library function if you wish:

```
public static int computeHashCode(Object... objects) {
   return Arrays.hashCode(objects);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The Apache Commons [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) has a reflection-based invocation that is similar to what you want.

```
public int hashCode() {
    return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(this);
}
```

Comment: This has pretty high overhead.  Your link leads me to suggest the normal `HashCodeBuilder` operation (using append) over this since I'm not sure what you're gaining through reflection.

Comment: I would, too, but this notation solves the problem he indirectly asked about not wanting to hand-code each field. Upvoting your answer for the `Arrays` based solution, as well.